# Unknown Reason Application crases

Tags: android, android-logcat

Android manifest code

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       package="com.example.takeit"
       :versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0" >

          <uses-sdk
             android:minSdkVersion="8"
              android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

          <application
             android:allowBackup="true"
              android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
               android:label="@string/app_name"
               android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
           <activity
               android:name="com.example.takeit.MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity2" />
    <activity android:name=".SignUP" />
    <activity android:name=".Menu" />
    <activity
        android:name=".QuestionActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_question" >
           </activity>
       </application>

   </manifest>
```

Logcat Error:
       08-17 02:12:35.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1154): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
       08-17 02:12:35.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):
       android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class 
        {com.example.takeit/android.view.Menu}; have you declared this activity in your
        AndroidManifest.xml?

```
  08-17 02:12:35.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):   at  
  android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1624)
  08-17 02:12:35.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):   at 
  android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1423)
  08-17 02:12:35.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):   at       
  android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3388)
  08-17 02:12:35.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):   at   
  android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3349)
  08-17 02:12:35.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):   at 
  android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3584)
  08-17 02:12:35.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):   at 
  android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3552)
  08-17 02:12:35.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):   at  
  com.example.takeit.MainActivity2$2.onClick(MainActivity2.java:67)
  08-17 02:12:35.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):   at 
  android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4212)
  08-17 02:12:35.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):   at 
  android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17476)
  08-17 02:12:35.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):   at 
  android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
  08-17 02:12:35.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):   at  
  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
  08-17 02:12:35.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):   at 
  android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
  08-17 02:12:35.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):   at   
  android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
  08-17 02:12:35.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):   at 
  java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  08-17 02:12:35.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):   at 
  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
  08-17 02:12:35.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):   at 
  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
  08-17 02:12:35.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):   at 
  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
  08-17 02:12:35.188: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):   at          
  dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can not understand why??

Comment: android.view.Menu thats wrong

Comment: i have declared it like com.example.takeit.Menu previously. but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

`ActivityNotFoundException` means that you have not declared your `Activity` in the manifest file. Simply add it there and you are good to go.

Also, why are you adding `android.view.Menu` to your manifest? You have to add **your Activity**.

Comment: checkout the manifest. i have declared my activity in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

You must use full package name with class
instead of

```
<activity android:name=".Menu" />
```

use

```
<activity android:name="com.example.takeit.Menu" />
```

It will be better to change class names to names with full packages.

Comment: I did it but it did not work. But after creating new class of that class and declare it to the manifest work for me. Thx

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the at the place you are starting the activity specifically where your are building the intent. most probably you are importing `android.view.Menu` and creating intent with `Menu.class` .If you are not using Menu Try replace `import android.view.Menu;` with `import com.example.takeit.Menu` or use FQN where you are building intent like 
`Intent i = new Intent(getContext(),com.example.takeit.Menu.class);`